# How to command+click to open url in new tab and switch to it in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a `div` element. The goal is to detect command+click to open some URL in the new tab **and switch to the new tab**. I've already done the detection and open.

The problem is: I use the same method to open URL: simply use `window.open()`.
When I press command and click, it **will not switch to the new tab**.
When I just click, it will switch.

```
<div
  onClick={(event) => {
    if (event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey) {
      // will not switch, but why?
      openLink('https://stackoverflow.com/');
    }
  }}
>
  command Click or ctrl Click
</div>

<div
  onClick={(event) => {
    // will switch
    openLink('https://stackoverflow.com/');
  }}
>
  just click
</div>
```

So I am wondering how to make command+click to open a new tab and switch to it? Thanks for your help.

Here is a minimal code snippet on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-roentgen-3kidt?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 2):

Problem sovled. I add `setTimeout` to it and it will switch. However, I still do not know why...

```
<div onClick={(event) => {
  if (event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey) {
    // it works, but why?
     setTimeout(() => openLink("https://stackoverflow.com/"));
  }
}}>
  command Click or ctrl Click
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `event.ctrlKey`, it will return a boolean that indicates if ctrl is pressed or not

```
<div onClick={(event) => {
      if (event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey) {
        // will not switch, but why?
        openLink("https://stackoverflow.com/");
      }
    }}
  >
    command Click or ctrl Click
</div>
```

Comment: That's my typo. It still will not switch to the new tab.

Answer (score 0):

This will work but for both simple click and cmd+click.

```
<div onClick={()=> window.open("someLink", "_blank")}>text</div>
```